# Firebase with Spring Boot- integration

Tags: spring, firebase

I would like to protect my REST API with Firebase Authorization. I found some tutorials, but they aren't clear. Also, I didn't find detailed documentation with step by step configuration. This what I have so far:

```
@Configuration
public class FirebaseConfig {

@Bean
public DatabaseReference firebaseDatabse() {
    DatabaseReference firebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    return firebase;
}

@Value("${rs.pscode.firebase.database.url}")
private String databaseUrl;

@Value("${rs.pscode.firebase.config.path}")
private String configPath;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {

    /**
     * https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup
     *
     * Create service account , download json
     */
    InputStream inputStream = FirebaseConfig.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(configPath);

    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder().setServiceAccount(inputStream)
            .setDatabaseUrl(databaseUrl).build();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
}
```

}

So I add url to Firebase and secret json generated on Firebase site.

Now, how can I configure it with? For example email and password which will be given by user?

I found this tutorial
http://pscode.rs/firebase-and-spring-boot-integration/,
but it seems a bit complex... I am stuck, please help me understand this configuration and integration with spring boot.

Comment: Have you find it?

Answer (score 0):

You have done the hard part, you just need to disable auto configuration for data-source and JPA if you are just using firebase, by adding this annotation to the main class, like this:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class })
```

after that you can create an user by using instance of `FirebaseAuth`, consider this code:

```
public void createUser(User user) {
    try {
        CreateRequest cr = new CreateRequest();
        cr.setUid(user.getUid()).setPassword("").setDisplayName(user.getDisplayName())
                .setPhoneNumber(user.getPhoneNumber()).setEmail(user.getEmail()).setEmailVerified(false)
                .setDisabled(true);

        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUser(cr);
    } catch (FirebaseAuthException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you to continue..